# How to make scrolling visible when hide modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

I have strange problem, I'm deleting rows using yajra datatable, now when Im clicking on Delete button its working fine but I wanted to hide modal automaticly after deleting, the problem is the scrolling is disable and when I want to delete again the modal show and hide in the same time

Delete Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="getDeleteId" href="#DeleteModal" uk-tooltip="title: Delete ; delay: 500 ; pos: top ;animation: uk-animation-scale-up" uk-toggle data-id="'.$data->id.'">
  <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Delete
</button>'
```

Modal:

```
<div id="DeleteModal" uk-modal> 
  <div class="uk-modal-dialog"> 
    <button class="uk-modal-close-default uk-padding-small" type="button" uk-close></button>                             
    <div class="uk-modal-header"> 
      <h4> Delete Sector </h4> 
    </div>                             
    <div class="modal-body uk-text-center"> 
      <h4>Are you sure want to delete this Sector?</h4>                         
    </div>                                 
    <div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right"> 
      <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>                                 
      <button class="uk-button uk-button-danger" type="button" id="SubmitDeleteForm">Delete</button>
    </div>                             
  </div>                         
</div>
```

JQuery

```
    method: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        $('.datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        $('#DeleteModal').hide();
```

Comment: Which modal library are you using?

Comment: Im using ukiti modal